# storing huge amount of records into classic asp cache object is SLOW

Tags: caching, asp-classic, object

we have some nasty legacy asp that is performing like a dog and i narrowed it down to because we are trying to store 15K+ records into the application cache object.  but that's not the killer.  before it stores it, it converts the ADO stream to XML then stores it.  this conversion of the huge record set to XML spikes the CPU and causes all kinds of havoc on users when it's happening. and unfortunately we do this XML conversion to read the cache a lot, causing site wide performance problems.

i don't have the resources to convert everything to .net.  so that's out.  but i need to obviously use caching, but int his case the caching is hurting instead of helping.   is there a more effecient way to store this data instead of doing this xml conversion to/from every time we read/update the cache?

Comment: I'm not sure why you "obviously" need to use caching.  How long does it take to just get the data you need in the first place (I mean skip the caching and go direct)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look here: [A Classic ASP Page Caching Object](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131054/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/032002-1.shtml)  ([cached version](http://64.233.163.132/search?q=cache:HqSEB-V4V5wJ:www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/032002-1.shtml+asp+classic+cache&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=br))

You can also to consider storing a `MSXML2.DOMDocument` directly into that application variable and to transform it using `MSXML2.XSLTemplate` (4.0 or later):

```
Set  oXSLProcessor = xmlStyle.CreateProcessor
With oXSLProcessor
    .Input = xmlDoc
    .Transform
     Response.Write .Output
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try Caprock Dictionary:
http://www.miniat.net/caprock-dictionary-object-component.asp